# Facing problem on Window Recreating with grid in Extjs-4

Tags: extjs, grid, window, extjs4

I need to render grid component with in the window(with close action destroy) so that i need to create new window and grid component instead of hide and show.

My code is working fine for the first time render but after closing window , i am unable to create it again, getting issue on layout.js

Line: 150
Error: Type mismatch.

```
 ************ getting issue in the below method and "dom" is undefined*********

moveItem : function(item, target, position) {
// Make sure target is a dom element
target = target.dom || target;
if (typeof position == 'number') {
position = target.childNodes[position];
}
target.insertBefore(item.el.dom, position || null); //dom is undefined 
item.container = Ext.get(target);
this.configureItem(item);
this.childrenChanged = true;
}


************
My controller and view of(grid and window) i have attached .Please identify where i am going wrong
************

Code:

**************************************************************************
Window Controller
**************************************************************************

Ext.define('Adapt.controller.versionManager.verManWinCont', {
            extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
            views : ['versionManager.verManWinView'],
            init : function() {             
                this.control({
                            'verManWindow' : {                      
                                afterrender : this.verManWindowAfterRender
                            }
                        });
            },
            verManWindowAfterRender : function(win, options) {
            });


**************************************************************************
window View
**************************************************************************
Ext.define('Adapt.view.versionManager.verManWinView' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    requires: ['Adapt.controller.versionManager.versionCont','Adapt.view.versionManager.versionGrdView', 'Adapt.store.versionManager.versionStor'],
    alias : 'widget.verManWindow',   
    constructor: function (config) {
    this.callParent([config]);},
     layout: 'fit',
     closeAction :'destroy',
    items: [{xtype: 'versionGrd'}],     
    autoShow :true,
    width : 580,
    height : 338,   
    closable : true,
    plain : true    
});

**************************************************************************
Grid Controller
**************************************************************************
Ext.define('Adapt.controller.versionManager.versionCont', {
            extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
            views : ['versionManager.versionGrdView'],          
            stores : ['versionManager.versionStor'],
            models : 'Adapt.model.versionManager.versionModl',      
            init : function() {

                debugger;
                this.control({
                            'versionGrd' : {
                                itemdblclick : this.versionGridDoubleClick,
                                afterrender : this.versionGridAfterRender

                            }
                        });

            },
            versionGridAfterRender : function(grid, options) {debugger;


            }           
        });



**************************************************************************
Grid View
**************************************************************************

Ext.define('Adapt.view.versionManager.versionGrdView' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    requires: ['Ext.grid.*','Adapt.view.versionManager.versionCreateView'],
    alias : 'widget.versionGrd',   
    store: 'versionManager.versionStor',
    columns:[
                {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'versionName',  flex: 1},
                {header: 'State', dataIndex: 'versionState', flex: 1}
            ],  
    constructor: function (config) {debugger;
    this.callParent([config]);},
    dockedItems: [] 

});
************************************************************************

(creating and showing in this handler)

In viewport Toolbar button handler(Controller)

this.getController('versionManager.verManWinCont');
this.getController('versionManager.versionCont');           
new Adapt.view.versionManager.verManWinView();//.show();
```

Thanks for your time
vinod.P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had **exactly** the same problem and solved it by changing the component creation to [factory functions](http://blog.extjs.eu/know-how/factory-functions-in-ext-extensions/).

The reason is that objects in JavaScript are **passed by reference**, so in the snippet below every grid instance shares the same columns object:

```
Ext.define('Adapt.view.versionManager.versionGrdView' ,{
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  columns:[
              { header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'versionName',  flex: 1 },
              { header: 'State', dataIndex: 'versionState', flex: 1 }
          ]
});
```

With the factory function approach you create the grid view like this:

```
Ext.define('Adapt.view.versionManager.versionGrdView' ,{
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

  initComponent: function() {
    config = Ext.apply({}, { items: this.buildColumns() });
    Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));
    this.callParent();
  }

  buildColumns: function() {
    return [
        { header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'versionName',  flex: 1 },
        { header: 'State', dataIndex: 'versionState', flex: 1 }
    ]
});
```

Now every new instance get its own copy of the columns array, which solves the problem that a part of the configuration has been destroyed. As a nice side effect, I also noticed that the startup of the application has reduced since I use only factory methods.

Comment: and also iam not forget to accept the answer/thank the person who took the time to read my query and providing the good answer.

Comment: hey @Netzpirat thanks for ur time provided and mainly with the good solution with explanation.

Comment: @Netzpirat, i also have many doubts in extj if u can, answer man, 1.how to destroy the controller and recreate when its needed again. that is when i destroy the window all should be recreated again(grid,store..etc)

Comment: @vineth: To destroy a controller, simply call `this.getController('YourController').destroy()` within your `Ext.application` and to create it again use `this.getController('YourController').init(this)`. I've made helper methods in my application controller for this.

Comment: thnks yar i will try it,and ping u back

Answer (score 0):

Check your Column array which is sent to reconfigure.